# in switch function how get case value in every case block

Tags: java

I’m using switch in my code and i wanna get case value in every case block. how can i get it?

```
switch(value)
{
    case Value1:
        function1(Value1); 
        // i want something like this : function1(getCaseValue)      
    break;
    case Value2:
        function1(Value2); 
    break;
    case Value3:
        function2(Value3);       
    break;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need that? It is not in Java, and you can't change case values runtime. This code is good as is.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve here, what is getCaseValue that you don't have in `value`(or `Value1` etc)?

Comment: Do you mean the value variable ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside of your case statements, you can call function with `value` variable `function1(value)`. Here is full code:

```java
switch(value) {
    case Value1:
        function1(value); 
    break;
    case Value2:
        function1(value); 
    break;
    case Value3:
        function2(value);       
    break;
}
```

If you will always call same function in specific set of values, you can even make your switch-case statements simpler:

```java
switch(value) {
    case Value1:
    case Value2:
        function1(value); 
    break;
    case Value3:
        function2(value);       
    break;
}
```

Comment: only (fictive) drawback is that `value` is not necessarily the same instance (`==`)  as the case value - but that only affects `String` and I can not think of any problem that could arise from that (unless using `==` inside the functions,or elsewhere)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same handling for different cases, instead of duplicating the handling, you can write clearer, simpler code by combining them like this:

```
switch (value) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
        function1(value);
        break;
}
```

If you want to add additional handling for other cases, add them, too:

```
case 3:
    function2(value);
    break;
```

and maybe inlude a default:

```
default:
    function3(value);
```